# React component with hooks as npm module

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, npm-publish

When I try to use React Hooks in module which I use as dependency it's fail. 
I'm getting a following error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
```

But if I use class-based component, it's ok. Why can this happen?

Here is excerpt from my `package.json`

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dist",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "qs": "^6.9.0",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3"
  }
}
```

Here is the component:

```
const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState('test')
  return <div>{state}</div>
}
```

Comment: it looks ok, can you share more code? like the way you import Test and use it in the different components. BTW you can't use hooks in a class component

Comment: I have the same issue - but when using hook in the function component which is in subfolder of consumer app, there is no problem, but when exported to npm, consumer fails. Maybe it's related to module system or target version? I tried es5 and es2017 both same error.

Comment: Are you using webpack? In that case what helped me was to set alias to react. There were really more react instances loaded as error states.

Comment: Jozef, should I set alias in the project or in the module I'm linking?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? @Twist

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are trying to use is **useState** and not **useEffect**:

```
const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState('test')
  return (<div>{state}</div>)
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, yes it’s my typo, but it doesn’t change anything, the result is the same

Comment: Could you please share the part of code where Test is rendered?

Comment: Just simple `export default` and `import Test from 'npm-package-name'`.

Answer (score 0):

You Cant Create A npm library with hooks you need to convert your function into class component and can be made as a library